# linq query Map repeating EDI data to XML structure

Tags: c#, linq, edi

Long story (see below for details) short, does anyone know I can frame a query to return repeating data into a known xml format, so each node and child elements are returned separately for a given criteria? 

**EDIT:** I guess my question boils down to: How can I query repeating data, and get a group of entries until the next occurrence of a duplicate?

UNB
UNH
MID
DAN
UNS
UNT
UNH
MID
DAN
UNS
UNT
UNH
MID
DAN
UNS
UNT
UNH
MID
DAN
UNS
UNT
UNH
MID
DAN
UNS
UNT
So in this case knowing that some segments repeat, how can I write a query that would return UNH - UNT, in  groups of:

UNH
MID
DAN
UNS
UNT

**Full Details**
I have a requirement to write a generic edi (EDIFACT) to xml mapper. Since the xml is structured, and known I have designed the application to import an xml file, extract and store the structure of the file using entity framework.
[image]
The Xml structure is stored as a self referencing entity called Translation. The translation contains the xml node, the Edifact segment name it maps to and the position of the composite and element to extract the value from. The translation also references itself as a parent/child association (to mirror the xml structure). The UI automatically matches content in each node to the segment, and composite and element positions.
The problem I have is how to separate repeating data into the appropriate repeating parent nodes:
[image: Desired XML structure on right, my output on left]
I am building this by extracting translations without parents, then walking down the tree recursively:

```
var rootTrans = (from t in Translations
                    where t.ParentID==null
                    select t).ToList();
//(msg is the EDI transmission with a collection of segments-each segment contains composites, each composite contains elements with the actual data eg- )

XElement root = new XElement(Tag.Replace(" ", ""));
foreach (var item in rootTrans)
{
    item.AddContentRecursive(root, msg);
}

var doc = new XDocument(root);



// AddContentRecursive
public void AddContentRecursive(XElement element, Transmission msg)
{
    // Find matching segments for this tag
    var segNodes = (from s in msg.Segments
                        where s.Value == Name
                        select GetElementValue(s, Positions)).DefaultIfEmpty(null);
    // simply add the matching nodes to the parent element
    if (Children.Count == 0)
    {
        var nodes = (from t in segNodes
                        select new XElement(Tag, t));
        element.Add(nodes);
    }
    else
    {
        var aNode = new XElement(Tag);
        element.Add(aNode);
        foreach (var chil in Children.OrderBy(c => c.DocumentOrder))
        {
            chil.AddContentRecursive(aNode, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

The EDI files are controlled by customers, and follow their own pattern, from the example below the UNH segment is a message header, and will repeat until a UNT. The translation entity for UNH has a property called tag (MessageHeader) and one called Name (UNH):

> UNH+ORDERR319952+ORDERR:1::OD'
>  MID+ORDERR319952+120818'
>   DAN+:ADVICE NOTE+TGBGU649'
>  MSD+CR'
>  SDT+0831824'
>   BDT+PIPUK+++++RB'
>  ART++46210JD000:::::PIPE WORK,RH'
>   DLV++2160:45'
>  DTP+120823:1700'
>  PIN+21'
>   TCO+:BLB+24+90'
>  CSG+0831824+F01-XJ10'
>  UNS+S'
>   UNT+14+ORDERR319952'
>  UNH+ORDERR340246+ORDERR:1::OD'
>   MID+ORDERR340246+120818'
>  DAN+:ADVICE NOTE+RRHBU636'
>   MSD+CR'
>  SDT+0831824'
>  BDT+PIPUK+++++RB'
>   ART++46210JD005:::::PIPE WORK,LH'
>  DLV++2160:45'
>   DTP+120823:1700'
>  PIN+21'
>  TCO+:BLB+24+90'
>   CSG+0831824+F01-XJ10'
>  UNS+S'
>  UNT+14+ORDERR340246'
>   UNH+ORDERR340247+ORDERR:1::OD'
>  MID+ORDERR340247+120818'
>   DAN+:ADVICE NOTE+RRHBU641'
>  MSD+CR'
>  SDT+0831824'
>   BDT+PIPUK+++++RB'
>  ART++46210JD600:::::PIPE WORK,RH'
>   DLV++4200:45'
>  DTP+120823:1700'
>  PIN+21'
>   TCO+:BAC4325+28+150'
>  CSG+0831824+F01-XJ10'
>  UNS+S'
>   UNT+14+ORDERR340247'

I have tried different combinations of queries, recursion, loops, and I know I'm missing something elementary, I'm in brick wall territory. Has anyone encountered this sort of problem? Any suggestions toward shaping the query, will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is there a way for you to cut this down to the essence? And what do the two XML listings and the listing `UNH+...` demonstrate? What does the output `AddContentRecursive` (essentially) look like and what _should_ it look like?

Comment: The image of the xml on the right is what I'm trying to get. In parsing the EDI plain text sequential file, my translation says whenever I encounter a UNH create a MessageHeader xml node, and then the MID segment is mapped to the DocumentNumber tag and so on. so from the sample above I should have two MessageHeader nodes, each with a corresponding DocumentNumber node, a parent DocumentReference node with several child nodes and so on. What I get, is all the parent nodes appearing just once, and a mess of all their child nodes together like the image on the left.

Comment: I suppose to start with a query that would return all the segment types in groups, so if there are 6 of each, 6 groups of 1 UNH, 1 MID, 1 DAN and so on, instead of what I'm getting now, it returns 6 UNH, 6 DAN and so on.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of solitary running in circles, a 10 minute discussion with a colleague yields a working solution. It was to let the segments determine the flow (instead of the mapping like I intended).

EDI data is sequential, and by extension the segments are also sequential, therefore it was a matter of stepping through each segment, paired with its translation or map, and using place holders to create and nest the XML nodes.

Not the prettiest (there are likely better ways of doing the same thing), but it works consistently:

```
// Get a collection of segments and maps
var SegsAndMaps = (from s in msg.Segments
                    join t in Maps on s.Value equals t.Name
                    orderby s.Id
                    select new { Segment = s, Map = t }).ToList();
// Set the placeholders
currentNode = null;
currentParent = null;
for (int i = 0; i < SegsAndMaps.Count; i++)
{   
    var item = SegsAndMaps[i];
    // Separate the properties from anonymous type for clarity
    var aMap = item.Map;
    var aSegment = item.Segment;
    var xml = aSegment.Xml(aMap);
    // If this map shares the same parent
    if (aMap.Parent == currentParent)
    {
        // Add the xml to the current node
        currentNode.Add(xml);
    }
    else
    {
        // Change of parent, walk up the tree to get the right parent
        var trans = aMap;
        while (currentParent != aMap.Parent)
        {
            trans = trans.Parent;
            currentParent = trans.Parent;
        }
        // Walk up the xml tree to find the parent tag to add this xml to
        currentNode = currentNode.Ancestors().DescendantsAndSelf(currentParent.Tag).FirstOrDefault();
        currentNode.Add(xml);
    }
    if (aMap.Children.Count > 0)
    {
        // If this map has child mappings, then update current parent to this, and its xml as the current node
        currentNode = xml;
        currentParent = aMap;
    }
}

var doc = new XDocument(currentNode);
```

Comment: please do yourself a favor and download EDI Notepad from Liaison.  It's free (with registration), and will help you understand the looping constructs of EDIFACT.  http://liaison.com/products/integrate/edi-notepad

Comment: Unfortunately, all the customers create and use their own variations of the EDI standard. So every new customer required a new mapping (currently hard coded in Delphi), I've now written a proof of concept generic mapper that converts EDIFACT to XML for ERP input. The notepad won't help in this case.